# Can't switch between Ubuntu and Windows 10 without entering BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Just need some help on this. Windows 10 killed my computer, I think it was updating or something but it killed my computer anyway. The only thing I could get up was my bios and recovery mode. I tried all things in the recovery mode, like Repair and Recover using Media (I made a Windows 10 disc using the media creation tool on the Microsoft website) long story short, nothing worked. I then decided to try Ubuntu and I managed to get a live version working and then decided to go the whole 9 yards and install it. The install wiped out everything but I had resigned myself to losing all my old docs and things. I really like Ubuntu and didn't really want to go back to Windows but there was one program which would not work with WINE so I decided to try to create a dual boot system with Windows 10. I did get Windows 10 on eventually but it wiped out Ubuntu. I tried again. This time I installed Ubuntu after Windows 10 and both OS are working fine now. The problem is when booting up. When I boot up I get 4 options:

```
* Ubuntu
  Advanced options for Ubuntu
  Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)
  System setup
```

If I boot into Ubuntu, everything is fine but if I try to boot into Windows I get the message:

```
/EndEntire
filepath: /ACPI(ao341do,0)/PCI(2,1f)/Sata(1,0,0)/HD(1,800,82000,7e8d39a0fa133f49,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image

Press any key to continue
```

When I press a key it then takes me back to the menu. The only way I can get Windows to load is to go into 'System setup' which takes me into the Bios screen and from there I have to change the boot order so that the windows boot manager is first. That means from then on the computer always boots into Windows and to get into Ubuntu I have to go into Bios when I first turn on the computer and change the boot order again. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I am new to Ubuntu but am reasonably confident around computers and don't mind using the Terminal.

Comment: Did you leave Windows fast start up or always on hibernation on? http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Turn off secure boot and see if the error goes away.  That's been a longstanding problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off secure boot worked! But as added info for anyone who follows along on the path.... I have a Phoenix SecureCore Tiano bios setup and secure boot is greyed out. You need to set a Supervisor Password in the Security tab. I saved the setting first and went into Windows, I then restarted the computer, went back into Bios, it will ask for the password. I could then disable the secure boot.